# Python не видит модуль при импорте

Tags: python, импорт

1. Существует следующий путь до папки:
   *E:\Programming\Python_projects\MyModules\ECG_class*
   В папке *ECG_class* имеется два файла:

   - *ecg.py*
   - *__ init __.py*
2. В файле *ecg.py* есть класс *ECG()*, который нужно импортировать.
3. В переменных среды PATH добавил путь:
   *E:\Programming\Python_projects\MyModules\ECG_class*

Импортировал следующим образом:

- *from ECG_class.ecg import ECG*

Но возвращает "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecg'". 
Что я упустил, что делаю не так, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: ``from ecg import ECG`` - так работает?

Comment: Путь надо добавить в переменную ``PYTHONPATH``, а не ``PATH``.

Comment: Так тоже не работает

Comment: Изначально нет. Нужно создать.

Comment: в какой папке лежит запускаемый скрипт?

Comment: Cоздал. Папка со скриптом лежит тут. C:\Users\Vlad\YandexDisk\Nauch_Rabota\ECG_arrythmia

Answer (score 2):

Проверил то, что вроде вы делаете. Добавил в `PATH` директорию. Положил туда `py`-файл. Затем открыл консоль `python`.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Увидел там свою директорию. Сделал команду `import <название скрипта>` - успех. (Правда есть вероятность, что эту директорию по `default`-у добавил `pycharm`.)

Если у вас не получается и нужно наверняка, то добавьте в переменную окружения PYTHONPATH свой каталог.

Также вы можете добавить сразу в скрипте:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path')
import myscript
```

Comment: При sys.path моей директории, которая добавлена в PATH, нет. Можете сказать почему?

Comment: Pythonpath отсутствовал, создал, добавил значением путь к модулю: E:\Programming\Python_projects\MyModules\ECG_class, но не импортирует. Пользуюсь IPython Notebook.

Comment: Спасибо, предложение с аппендом в path работает, но хотелось бы от этого избавиться, поэтому и решил добавить в переменные среды путь к папке со всеми своими модулями. Но проблема еще не решена)

Comment: @Gagampy добавьте в pythonpath, будет наверняка

Answer (score 2):

В Python 3 существует несколько способов импорта: абсолютный и относительный.

При абсолютном импорте поиск модуля выполняется из путей из списка os.path

```
from module_name import class_name # обсолютный имопрт
```

При таком иморте поиск будет идти по этим путям:

```
import os.path
print(os.path)
```

Если нужно испортировать модуль, который находится внутри текущего то нужно импортировать по отностиельному пути:

```
from .module_name import class_name
```

При таком способе поиск модуля будет выполнятся в текущей директории в пакете модулей или модуле module_name. Тут важно откуда именно запускается ваша программа. Про систему импорта пакетов можно узнать тут: https://youtu.be/-xcaGEkWbCs